# excel object methods and properties not showing up with uft 14.2 editor

Tags: excel, qtp

excel object methods and properties not showing up with descriptive programming with uft 14.2 editor to work around. Does it required any addin or need any option to be checked?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You need to provide a lot more information than just that.. like what are you attempting to do and what you have tried so far? To give you a start, when you say: `excel object methods and properties not showing up`.. do you mean **intellisense** options?

Comment: the drop down list that show in expert or editor view for the steps. Do need any file like dll for this. does not show for excel, database, file scripting objects. Intellisense only shows for the objects in the object repository. Any files left or need any add-ins

Comment: As far as I am aware, UFT doesn't provide intellisense for external objects. You can use something like VBSEditor to develop your script which will give you intellisense